# Typing array of objects in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript

Using typescript to type an array of objects:

Here are the interfaces:

```
export interface IUser {
  id: string;
  order: number;
}

export interface IUsersLogin {
  result: number;
  UserId: string;
}

export interface IUsersUsers {
  id: number;
  order: number;
}

export interface IOriginalData {
  Users?: IUser[];
  UsersLogins?: IUsersLogin[];
  UsersUsers?: IUsersUsers[];
}
```

Here I create an object using this interfaces:

```
const originalData: IOriginalData = {
  Users: [
    {
      id: "e4e2bb46-c210-4a47-9e84-f45c789fcec1",
      order: 1
    },
    {
      id: "b95274c9-3d26-4ce3-98b2-77dce5bd7aae",
      order: 2
    }
  ],
  UsersLogins: [
    {
      result: 1,
      UserId: "e4e2bb46-c210-4a47-9e84-f45c789fcec1"
    },
    {
      result: 0,
      UserId: "b95274c9-3d26-4ce3-98b2-77dce5bd7aae"
    }
  ],
  UsersUsers: [
    {
      id: 1,
      order: 0
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      order: 0
    }
  ]
};
```

And here I manipulate the data of this object to push it into another object:

```
interface IPushedDataItem {
  data: IUser | IUsersLogin | IUsersUsers;
}

type TypePushedData = Array<IPushedDataItem>;

let pushedData: TypePushedData = [];
Object.keys(originalData).forEach(item => {
  pushedData.push({
    data: originalData[item]
  });
});
```

In this process, I cant type `pushedData` properly, and it complains with `data:originalData[item]`.

You can find this in the TypeScript playgound:

http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgSQFUBnNOAbwCg5EATALjmJimQHMBuauaWtRpAFcAtgCM0XAL6VKoSLEQo0WXARJpiAGQhtkFblGDFBAGxgCR4qFxrqo+BkxbspMudHjJUGHHiKkoYjtifRoERyExCW5efjhIq1dZcA9FbxU-AHlWXSRMEwARTBhMULhggH5GfzQAbQBdG3KArR1kYiq1Fu1chqbgyuqBlr7KaUpsCCRmHhzkfKKS6uyEXIXi0oBeMuDGWu4aKhpjukYAImAAFmAAJlFRS4A2AFpsG4BGAAZny8xLgHZngBOYAADkuz3QlwArNh-qCgehcNh3mcADQHY6xKCMd6YyQYk5HE6nOBnURA6E3f6XbBA54AZloNxetOADOBoNEN2e-3+tFw0NEtH+mEwwHRmJo2MYN3x3HqhOaGh67T2mOJJ0MxjMuKVJzsDnOV1u9yerw+31+AOBYIhUNh8MRyNR+P1ZS1RlM5jgn3dtgCRrJFKpNLpjOZrNwHKBXJ5fIFwCFIrFEvlNEV3GGGnVRKlpPe-tmfBxvrdGvz4VlRZlZZO0gzYy4lC8yl8BAACoJiAALYC0RaYfCoYRlWgbIYBOAAHy6KraSBnc8CwSSMAAnmA8AAVTfALu9-uDuDbACCUCgmHXAB58Ae+wONsPgMIAHzNkzAeBgbsPweMXct3vI8NhPOBRkyUQACtgGwGAADoAGtgHXYgAApoFWeZCg2ABKeD0GgABRHAezQhARxPV8yh-Q9HxKeDaLIzU4HHJZZiwvIcJKWoKJfepuEkXCpGEyggA

Any help will be welcome!

Comment: What do you want `pushedData` to contain? The type signature you've given it says it expects objects with a `data` property, but your code doesn't do that...

Answer (score 1):

1. extend the definition of `originalData` to support indexer:

```
const originalData: IOriginalData & { [key: string]: (IUser | IUsersLogin | IUsersUsers)[] }
```

2. you must iterate over array of items accessed by key when adding them to `pushedData` because it's not a single item:

```
Object.keys(originalData).forEach(item => {
  const subItems = originalData[item];
  if (subItems) {
    for (const subItem of originalData[item]) {
      pushedData.push({
        data: subItem
      });
    }
  }
});
```

the overall code is the following:

```
export interface IUser {
  id: string;
  order: number;
}

export interface IUsersLogin {
  result: number;
  UserId: string;
}

export interface IUsersUsers {
  id: number;
  order: number;
}

export interface IOriginalData {
  Users?: IUser[];
  UsersLogins?: IUsersLogin[];
  UsersUsers?: IUsersUsers[];
}

const originalData: IOriginalData & { [key: string]: (IUser | IUsersLogin | IUsersUsers)[] } = {
  Users: [
    {
      id: "e4e2bb46-c210-4a47-9e84-f45c789fcec1",
      order: 1
    },
    {
      id: "b95274c9-3d26-4ce3-98b2-77dce5bd7aae",
      order: 2
    }
  ],
  UsersLogins: [
    {
      result: 1,
      UserId: "e4e2bb46-c210-4a47-9e84-f45c789fcec1"
    },
    {
      result: 0,
      UserId: "b95274c9-3d26-4ce3-98b2-77dce5bd7aae"
    }
  ],
  UsersUsers: [
    {
      id: 1,
      order: 0
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      order: 0
    }
  ]
};

interface IPushedDataItem {
  data: IUser | IUsersLogin | IUsersUsers;
}

type TypePushedData = Array<IPushedDataItem>;

let pushedData: TypePushedData = [];
Object.keys(originalData).forEach(item => {
  const subItems = originalData[item];
  if (subItems) {
    for (const subItem of originalData[item]) {
      pushedData.push({
        data: subItem
      });
    }
  }
});
```

**UPDATE**

If you want to have a more strict check of string key, you can define it using `in keyof` syntax:

```
const originalData: IOriginalData & { [key in keyof IOriginalData]: (IUser | IUsersLogin | IUsersUsers)[] }
```

Though it will also require to cast the result of `Object.keys(originalData)` to `(keyof IOriginalData)[]`.

The overall code will be the following:

```
export interface IUser {
  id: string;
  order: number;
}

export interface IUsersLogin {
  result: number;
  UserId: string;
}

export interface IUsersUsers {
  id: number;
  order: number;
}

export interface IOriginalData {
  Users?: IUser[];
  UsersLogins?: IUsersLogin[];
  UsersUsers?: IUsersUsers[];
}

export type OriginalDataUnion = IUser | IUsersLogin | IUsersUsers;

const originalData: IOriginalData & { [key in keyof IOriginalData]: OriginalDataUnion[] } = {
  Users: [
    {
      id: "e4e2bb46-c210-4a47-9e84-f45c789fcec1",
      order: 1
    },
    {
      id: "b95274c9-3d26-4ce3-98b2-77dce5bd7aae",
      order: 2
    }
  ],
  UsersLogins: [
    {
      result: 1,
      UserId: "e4e2bb46-c210-4a47-9e84-f45c789fcec1"
    },
    {
      result: 0,
      UserId: "b95274c9-3d26-4ce3-98b2-77dce5bd7aae"
    }
  ],
  UsersUsers: [
    {
      id: 1,
      order: 0
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      order: 0
    }
  ]
};

interface IPushedDataItem {
  data: OriginalDataUnion;
}

type TypePushedData = Array<IPushedDataItem>;

let pushedData: TypePushedData = [];
for (const item of Object.keys(originalData) as (keyof IOriginalData)[]) {
  const subItems = originalData[item];
  if (subItems) {
    for (const subItem of subItems) {
      pushedData.push({
        data: subItem
      });
    }    
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't think blindly adding `[key: string]`  is such a good idea. Imagine we mistype `Users: ` as `Userz: ` - with your type TS will happily allow that.

Comment: yes, if you also plan to use explicit keys instead of data provided by `Object.keys`. added an example with `in keyof` syntax but it requires one explicit cast

Comment: @georg, I agree with you:  using `[n: string]` (or `[key: string]`) will allow a mistaken key at `originalData`, for example, `mistake: [ { id: "e4e2bb46-c210-4a47-9e84-f45c789fcec1", order: 1 } ]`.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of problems there.

`originalData` doesn't have an index signature. In general, because of TypeScript's static typing nature, highly-dynamic code (such as code going through all the properties of an object by name using `Objct.keys`) tends to be problematic because the static type information is lost, since the properties have different value types. If you can void doing that, which you can in your case, that's probably better.

Another issue is that you've given `pushedData` a type that expects an array of objects with a `data` property, but your code doesn't do that, it pushes the `IUser` etc. objects directly into the array instead of pushing objects where the `data` property is that `IUser` etc. object. I suspect you meant `IPushedDataItem` to be:

```
type IPushedDataItem  = IUser | IUsersLogin | IUsersUsers;
```

Assuming I'm correct about that, you can then create `pushedData` like this:

```
let pushedData: TypePushedData = [
    ...(originalData.Users ? originalData.Users : []),
    ...(originalData.UsersLogins ? originalData.UsersLogins : []),
    ...(originalData.UsersUsers ? originalData.UsersUsers : []),
];
```

[Live on the playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgSQFUBnNOAbwCg5EATALjmJimQHMBuauaWtRpAFcAtgCM0XAL6VKoSLEQo0WXARJpiAGQhtkFblGDFBAGxgCR4qFxrqo+BkxbspMudHjJUGHHiKkoYjtifRoERyExCW5efjhIq1dZcA9FbxU-AHlWXSRMEwARTBhMULhggH5GfzQAbQBdG3KArR1kYiq1Fu1chqbgyuqBlr7KaUpsCCRmHhzkfKKS6uyEXIXi0oBeMuDGWu4aKhpjukYAImAAFmAAJlFRS4A2AFpsG4BGAAZny8xLgHZngBOYAADkuz3QlwArNh-qCgehcNh3mcADQHY6xKCMd6YyQYk5HE6nOBnURA6E3f6XbBA54AZloNxetOADOBoNEN2e-3+tFw0NEtH+mEwwHRmJo2MYN3x3HqhOaGh67T2mOJJ0MxjMuKVJzsDnOV1u9yerw+31+AOBYIhUNh8MRyNR+P1ZS1RlM5jgn3dtgCRrJFKpNLpjOZrNwHKBXJ5fIFwCFIrFEvlNEV3GGGnVRKlpPe-tmfBxvrdGvz4VlRZlZZO0gzYy4lBgAE8wH4AAqCYgAC2AtEWmHwqGENG2NSgcAAPl0VW0kDO54Fgs22x24AAVdvAbt9gdDuDbACCUCgmFbAB58Hv+4ONiPgMIAHzNkzAeBgHt3oeMbcd28Dw2I84H2E4ADpIIACmgVZ5kKDZwOCOAKlmOC8gQkokJaOA9nqABKd1IPAmC5gwodsPnXIQlQ2C1kwzBKMCVVplw0CCKI6C6Pgijs0CFC0Po3iWmQvDCMoRogA)

This also has the advantage of giving you a defined order to the entries in the resulting array (whereas with `Object.keys`, there is no guaranteed order per the specification, although all modern engines follow the same order for own properties as they would for `getOwnPropertyKeys`, it's just not guaranteed).

That would be less complicated if you made the properties non-optional (removed the `?` in the properties in `IOriginalData`). Then it would be just:

```
let pushedData: TypePushedData = [
    ...originalData.Users,
    ...originalData.UsersLogins,
    ...originalData.UsersUsers,
];
```

---

If you really want objects with a `data` property instead (your original version of `IPushedDataItem`), then you'd use `map`:

```
let pushedData: TypePushedData = [
    ...(originalData.Users ? originalData.Users.map(data => ({data})) : []),
    ...(originalData.UsersLogins ? originalData.UsersLogins.map(data => ({data})) : []),
    ...(originalData.UsersUsers ? originalData.UsersUsers.map(data => ({data})) : []),
];
```

[Live on the playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgSQFUBnNOAbwCg5EATALjmJimQHMBuauaWtRpAFcAtgCM0XAL6VKoSLEQo0WXARJpiAGQhtkFblGDFBAGxgCR4qFxrqo+BkxbspMudHjJUGHHiKkoYjtifRoERyExCW5efjhIq1dZcA9FbxU-AHlWXSRMEwARTBhMULhggH5GfzQAbQBdG3KArR1kYiq1Fu1chqbgyuqBlr7KaUpsCCRmHhzkfKKS6uyEXIXi0oBeMuDGWu4aKhpjukYAImAAFmAAJlFRS4A2AFpsG4BGAAZny8xLgHZngBOYAADkuz3QlwArNh-qCgehcNh3mcADQHY6xKCMd6YyQYk5HE6nOBnURA6E3f6XbBA54AZloNxetOADOBoNEN2e-3+tFw0NEtH+mEwwHRmJo2MYN3x3HqhOaGh67T2mOJJ0MxjMuKVJzsDnOV1u9yerw+31+AOBYIhUNh8MRyNR+P1ZS1RlM5jgn3dtgCRrJFKpNLpjOZrNwHKBXJ5fIFwCFIrFEvlNEV3GGGnVRKlpPe-tmfBxvrdGvz4VlRZlZZO0gzYy4lC8yl8BAACoJiAALYC0RaYfCoYRlWgbIYBOAAHy6KraSBnc8CwSSMAAnmA8AAVTfALu9-uDuDbACCUCgmHXAB58Ae+wONsPgMIAHzNkzAeBgbsPweMXct3vI8NhPOB9hOAA6aCAApoFWeZCg2SDgjgCpZgQvIkJKFCWkg4RMDAGDxxKE9XzgGDyBIzBJAASlouA9nqWj3WgyC4LmLDB1w+dchCdD4LWbDMB4wJVWmfDCOI0DNnIyjqLohimJYzE2I4zD1hw7NAjQjChO47TiEkojqLIiiqI2RTGPA5iMUaIA)

...which again would be simpler if the properties weren't optional.

Answer (score 0):

Let's simplify your example a bit:

```
export interface A { s: string }
export interface B { n: number }
export interface C { b: boolean }

export interface All {
    A: A;
    B: B;
    C: C;
}

//

let all: All = {
    A: {s: "s"},
    B: {n: 33},
    C: {b: true},
};

let other: Array<A | B | C> = [];
```

Now, this

```
Object.keys(all).forEach(k => other.push(all[k]))
```

will fail, because `Object.keys` is inferred as `Array<string>` and not `Array<keyof All>` as one might expect. See [this comment](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/12253#issuecomment-263132208) as to why.

However, the same comment says that `for k in obj` infers `k` as `keyof`  when using generics. We can use that to write our own strict version of `Object.keys`:

```
function strictKeys<T>(o: T): Array<keyof T> {
    let a = [];
    for (let k in o)
        a.push(k);
    return a;
}
```

and now

```
strictKeys(all).forEach(k => other.push(all[k]))
```

computes correctly!

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgSQFUBnNOAbwCg4bEATALjmJimQHMBua26OtJkgCuAWwBGabgF9KlUJFiIUaLLgIk0xADIR2yCjxpRgxIQBsYg0RKjdacDVHyNmrDtNnzo8ZKgw48IlIoYkdiA3sEF2FxSUM4PgE4GJsPOXBvJT9VQIB5Nj0kTDMAEUwYTAjaMIB+JiC0AG0AXTtq4O1dZGI69Q6dQpa2mjDa+tGOocoZSmwIJBYEguRisor6-IRC1fLKgF4qkY6mRvj7KntL2iimACJgABZgACYxMQeANgBabGeARgADF8HpgHgB2L4ATmAAA4Hl90A8AKzYMEwyHoXDYP63AA0ZyuS34UCYfwJNCk+MJh2p9DuYkhSOeYIe2EhXwAzHRnt9WcAOVCYWJnl8wWC6LgkWI6GDMJhgHjyZdEiS4M8lTJ7M0qe1NANuiclRdaUYTOZLHA-jqTY5nHdHi83p8fv8gSDwVDYfDESi0RisTiNdbLsaTcZTBYmADg9TbS5bgymSy2ZzubzcALIUKRWKJcApTK5QqNfFtfEJppDdTQ7SbpaY4SVVGg0alZEXM8G1cm3AASWtdNuJRfCoAgQAApCYgAC2AdDWmHwqBENLou3GwTgAB8+nqukht7uQmE0jAAJ5gPAAFQvwEnM7nC7gB3w99n892S+AIimlHQQiQbAYAQeZXDYICAGlgDPYgAB4rwAPgACggJgrwASiYABBKAoEwM9YIAa2giB0DgRCaTMYB4H2OApnsdBoDgJCqPgQilASdClUwAA6MAp2nJDCPQ4Y4GMGAhCgA9MDSVi4H4h8P3WcjbzfR9dmfOjWlkRioGYuT2NIsCEEg6DiBQ5YilKXZ0K4mhdP06i4DXCoEjI6AthWayKkaQjmgAQjs2gFPfBc+IEpDyBczApCCuBKCAA)

Comment: I don't like the idea of using this custom `strictKeys`, but the explanation is great. Thanks!